# Perl finding duplicates (polishing up the existing code)

Tags: perl, duplicates, editing

Hey All below is my code:

```
#!/bin/usr/perl

@words = ();
@dup = ();

print "Please enter your query sentence:\n";
$input = <STDIN>;
chomp $input;

@words = split(/ /, $input);
@sort  = sort { "\L$a" cmp "\L$b" } @words;
for $n ( 0..$#sort ) {
   if (lc $sort[$n] eq lc $sort[($n+1)]) {
      push (@dup, $sort[$n]);
   }
   else {
      $n+=1;
   }
 }

 if ( @dup == () ) { 
    print "There are no duplicates in the query sentence.\n";
 }
 else {
    print "@dup \n";
 }
```

The problem I am having is if the word appears more than twice it appears in @dup for each additional occurrence. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please provide sample input and result you expect

Comment: for example if my query is "Nature’s first green is gold Her hardest hue to hold Her early leaf’s a flower But only so an hour Then leaf subsides to leaf So Eden sank to grief So dawn goes down to day Nothing gold can stay" It should print the following as the output: gold her leaf so to    but what my code prints out is gold her leaf so so to to to

Comment: My code and I believe other answers should do the trick. It is always a good idea to use a HASH when you need to count unique items.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much simpler to use a Hash, which will still allow you to track duplicates and saves you from needing to presort your Array:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

print "Please enter your query sentence:\n";
my $input = <STDIN>;
chomp $input;
my @words = split /\s+/, $input;

my %unique_elems;
for my $word ( @words ) {
   $unique_elems{$word}++;
}

if ( scalar keys %unique_elems == scalar @words ) { 
   print "There are no duplicates in the query sentence.\n";
}
else {
   my @dups = grep { $unique_elem{$_} > 1 } keys %unique_elems;  
   print join ',', @dups;
   print "\n";
}
```

A couple notes:

1. You should always `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of your scripts, it will save you more time than you would think
2. You should be using `my` to declare lexical variables instead of declaring globals

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
#!/bin/usr/perl
@words = ();
@dup = ();
print "Please enter your query sentence:\n";
$input = <STDIN>;
chomp $input;
@words = split(/ /, $input);
@sort= sort {"\L$a" cmp "\L$b"}@words;
%hash;
for $n (0..$#sort) {
        if (lc $sort[$n] eq lc $sort[($n+1)]) {
                if(!defined $hash{$sort[$n]}) {
                    push (@dup, $sort[$n]);
                    $hash{$sort[$n]}=1;
                }
        }
        else {$n+=1;}
            }
if (@dup==()){print "There are no duplicates in the query sentence.\n";}
else {print "@dup \n";}
```

just defined an additional hash %hash to keep the unique entries in the array.

Comment: This will still add duplicates to @dup, because you don't check if the values are already in the hash.

Comment: bro check that again...probably you have missed this part...push (@dup, $sort[$n]) if(!defined $hash{$sort[$n]});

Comment: whoops, my mistake. If you moved into the if condition you could avoid reassigning 1 to the hash key each time.

Comment: yes, you can put both the statement inside the if block

Comment: Always include [`use strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY perl script.  This is first advise that you should share with new coders, and definitely should be the style of code that one should model when suggested a solution.  Welcome to SO, and cheers.

Comment: This seems to work except that I still have So and so listed when i use the following as a query sequence: "Nature’s first green is gold Her hardest hue to hold Her early leaf’s a flower But only so an hour Then leaf subsides to leaf So Eden sank to grief So dawn goes down to day Nothing gold can stay ". Is there a way to remove the case sensitivity?

Comment: yeah..there is always a way to get something done...now while storing the values in hash use like this $hash{uc($sort[$n])}...uc function will change the keys to uppercase and will do everything else you want :)

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! I am still learning, and I appreciate your help and patience! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
print "Please enter your query sentence:\n";
$input = <STDIN>;
chomp $input;
my @words = split /\s+/, $input;
my %words;
foreach my $word(@words) {
    $words{lc($word)}++;
}
my @dup = grep {$words{$_} > 1} keys %words;
if (@dup == 0) { 
    print "There are no duplicates in the query sentence.\n";
 }
 else {
    print "@dup \n";
 }
```